# wheeled 2D character controller platform edges problem

Tags: physics

I have built a little wheeled 2D character controller (a rectangle for the body and a circle for the legs with a motor joint). Everything is ok but the problem is that when the player reaches the edge of a platform it goes down a little because the the the legs part is a circle. How do you ussually fix this kind of behaviour?

This image shows the problem when the character walks close to the platform edge:

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: Make the character not get as close to the edge of platforms?

Comment: Sorry, but don't understand what you mean. Won't this be odd to the player? Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: I think an image of the situation would make it easier to understand what the problem is and provide potential solutions.

Comment: I have added a picture showing the problem.

Comment: @Notbad, I mean, that's what would physically happen with a circle and box. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected this behaviour. It is sensible, what I would like to know is how could I fix this issue. I guess dirty tricks must be applied to fix this but who knows... For example, Should I be raycasting into the ground and use the circle just work to slide the hero over the ground? I have seen games using this techique (devoloper let me know) and they don't suffer from this issue. I have done tests using different things that came to mind but did not fidn a goodl solution/feeling.

Comment: @Notbad: you seem to be ignoring the solution of just not using a box+circle for your character shape. You still have to solve all the same problems that a classic box-shape character will have, plus now you have to solve new ones, so this seems to me to be a bad design.

Comment: Could you be more specific about this "feeling" you're looking for that the current setup isn't giving? This question would work way better if phrased in the form "how do I do X", with X described as closely as you can.

Comment: I could reword it too... How to achieve old school feeling (mario, etc...) with the setup I exposed. I would like to keep physic collisions on this character but with getting mario-like control feeling. This questiosn was posted some months ago, at this time I think I would use a box kinematic body with some raycasts for the collisions. Anyway, I have seen other using the "wheeled way" and this is way I asked the question taht way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd limit the movement near the edge of the platform. So, when the wheel base is stopped near the edge make the character halt, and wobble, and only if the player keeps on pushing will they go off the edge. You can control the "dismount" animation, too.

Of course, if the player just pushes constantly off the edge you must honour their intent and just move them off the platform.

Comment: Sorry, but again, this is a constrain I don't want to add to the game.